# bower install angular-touch doesn't give me latest version

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm using angular@build-1.30.*

But when I do `bower install angular-touch` it only gives me 1.2 for angular-touch. The latest is 1.3.0 build of version of angular I'm using.

https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to specify version in bower.json first since these are unstable:

```
"angular-touch": ">=1.3.*"
```